# Route Output files from Robot Framework to specific location

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, robotframework

I have a requirement of implementing test automation for specific modules and keep them separated from each other. So I have a folder structure like this:

[image]

What I want to achieve is, to get reports, output, and logs for both subsets to be stored in their respective results folder.

I know this can be achieved via CLI but I want to know if there's a way I can configure it somewhere so it pickups the output folder location depending on the test run.

I went through other solutions but mostly it is through CLI. I am looking for a configuration preferably for VS Code.

Comment: Does `task.json` help? Read [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks) for more details.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT I want the flexibility to run 1 or multiple tests at once, And as I read through the document this would need to be configured in task.json at once. or have multiple task files. Since my test folder can 100+test, so, I don't think it would work or at least it'll require additional effort to manage tasks separately. Appreciate your help though.